# I have labelled a table, but it says that the reference is undefined

Tags: labels, threeparttable

I have referenced an appendix table in the main text. Depending on where I put the label, I either

1. Get an error message saying that the reference is undefined (and the main text reads 'Table ??')
2. Reference the table using the name of the whole section, so it is 'Table B' not 'Table B1' (the table appears in section B of the appendix).

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong? Here is a MWE which illustrates the first case ('Table ??'):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, hyperref, amsmath,amsfonts, bm, eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,mathtools,natbib, xcolor,setspace,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array, parskip, bbm, csquotes, multirow, booktabs,caption}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. I will try to reference Table \ref{overview}


\clearpage

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\newpage

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Proofs} \label{proofs}

Here are some proofs

\newpage

\section{Additional tables and figures} \label{tables_figures}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{B\arabic{table}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{B\arabic{figure}}

\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cclcc}
\hline
\caption{Overview}\label{overview}
Moose & Rabbit & \hspace{3em}Deer      & Elephant & Mango \\ \hline
1                & Yes             & a & 10              & 18                    \\
2                & Yes             & b & 10              & 18                    \\
3                & No              & c & 10              & 10                    \\
4                & No              & d & 10              & 10                    \\
5                & No              & e           & 9               & 10                    \\
6                & No              & e           & 9               & 10                    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item \hspace{-0.2em}\textit{Notes}: Here are some notes...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}


\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Here is is a MWE which illustrates the second case ('Table B'):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, hyperref, amsmath,amsfonts, bm, eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,mathtools,natbib, xcolor,setspace,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array, parskip, bbm, csquotes, multirow, booktabs,caption}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. I will try to reference Table \ref{overview}


\clearpage

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\newpage

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Proofs} \label{proofs}

Here are some proofs

\newpage

\section{Additional tables and figures} \label{tables_figures}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{B\arabic{table}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{B\arabic{figure}}

\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cclcc}
\hline
\caption{Overview}
Moose & Rabbit & \hspace{3em}Deer      & Elephant & Mango \\ \hline
1                & Yes             & a & 10              & 18                    \\
2                & Yes             & b & 10              & 18                    \\
3                & No              & c & 10              & 10                    \\
4                & No              & d & 10              & 10                    \\
5                & No              & e           & 9               & 10                    \\
6                & No              & e           & 9               & 10                    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item \hspace{-0.2em}\textit{Notes}: Here are some notes...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{overview}
\end{center}


\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be getting an error message about the `\caption` directive not occurring inside a LaTeX "float" -- the main examples of which are `table` and `figure`. Also, `\caption` directives are *never* allowed inside `tabular` environments. You need to (a) embed the `threeparttable` material in a `table` environment and (b) place the `\caption{Overview}` instruction immediately after `\begin{threeparttable}` and before `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I actually just figured that out! Will delete Q

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX must be issueing two separate error messages related to the table.

- `\caption` directives are not allowed outside of LaTeX floats (such as `table` and `figure`).
- `\caption` directives are not allowed inside `tabular` environments.

The remedy? (a) encase the `threeparttable` material in a `table` environment. (b) Remove the `\caption` directive from its current place and insert it right after `\begin{threeparttable}` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%% I've left some comments next to some of your preamble directives
\usepackage{amssymb, 
  hyperref, 
  %amsmath,  % is loaded automatically by mathtools
  %amsfonts, % is loaded automatically by amssymb
  bm, eurosym, geometry, ulem, graphicx, caption, 
  mathtools, natbib, xcolor, setspace, comment, 
  footmisc, 
  %%caption, % don't load packages twice
  pdflscape,
  %%subfigure,  % obsolete and incompatible with caption package
  array, parskip, bbm, csquotes, multirow, booktabs %,
  %%caption  % and most definitely don't load a package three times!
  }
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} % <-- new (default is '1\baselineskip')
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue} % <-- new

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}
%% "margin=1in" is a lot easier than "left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in"
\geometry{margin=1in}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection\arabic{figure}}

\section{Proofs} \label{proofs}

Here are some proofs

\newpage

\section{Additional tables and figures} \label{tables_figures}

\begin{table}[ht] % <-- new
\centering % <-- new
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Overview}  % <-- new location
\label{overview}
\begin{tabular}{@{} cclcc @{}}
\toprule
Moose & Rabbit & Deer & Elephant & Mango \\ 
\midrule
1     & Yes    & a    & 10       & 18    \\
2     & Yes    & b    & 10       & 18    \\
3     & No     & c    & 10       & 10    \\
4     & No     & d    & 10       & 10    \\
5     & No     & e    &  9       & 10    \\
6     & No     & e    &  9       & 10    \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]\hspace{-0.2em}\textit{Notes}: Here are some notes \dots

\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} % <-- new

A cross-reference to \autoref{overview}.

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```